# Expanding div as much as possible with only css?

Tags: html, css

This is what i am trying to do;

[image: scheme]

Is this even possible?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: `Divs` take all available horizontal space already on default. (Unless it is floating)

Comment: @KhawerZeshan — No. 100% would include the space already taken up by the section marked "fixed width".

Comment: @Cthulhu — Presumably it *is* floating (or has some other properties applied to stop it taking up the whole width) since it is *next to another element*

Comment: @Quentin Flex is not well supported, especially IE will spoil the game, than you need to have 10 kinds of polyfills and stuff...

Comment: @Mr.Alien — There is a reason I pointed at a URL which describes the level of browser support.

Comment: @Quentin Yea, even I love using fancy stuff but we are always bound to base things :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hwfNK/)

```
.wrap {
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.left {
    height: 400px;
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.max {
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: 130px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Explanation: `float: left;` your first `div` and move other element to the right using `margin-left: fixed-div-width + some extra space` and than encapsulate both elements in a wrapper. Just a side note, don't forget to clear your floating elements

Comment: It's a bit dirty but it's required for cross-browser support, so i will use it. Thanks.

Comment: @m_poorUser nothing dirty here, this is the only way if you are ignoring the flex box, else you need to use scripts :)

Comment: I said dirty because you need to change .max's margin-left if you change width of .left. But hey, i've done worse things for compatibility :)

Comment: @m_poorUser haha yes, we are web dev.. so till we don't have a specific set of rules to follow and till browsers keep ignoring the wrong approaches, dirty will stay... always..